# Merge an overlapping date range to form a timeline

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset that I need to merge on overlapping date range to form a timeline to indicate Active and Not Active stages of a patient. I'm looking for a t-sql script that could transform this data.

This is a sample dataset:

```
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| Practice | PatID | AgeAtActiveStart | AgeAtActiveEnd | ActiveStart | ActiveEnd  |
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| Prac1    | P1    |               58 |             72 | 2003-05-09  | 2017-12-22 |
| Prac1    | P1    |               59 |             60 | 2004-03-30  | 2005-03-30 |
| Prac1    | P1    |               60 |             63 | 2005-12-14  | 2008-04-29 |
| Prac1    | P1    |               63 |             65 | 2008-07-31  | 2010-06-17 |
| Prac1    | P1    |               65 |             68 | 2010-07-30  | 2013-08-07 |
| Prac1    | P1    |               69 |             72 | 2014-03-06  | 2018-01-04 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               32 |             33 | 2004-12-08  | 2006-04-01 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               32 |             33 | 2005-07-18  | 2006-07-18 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               33 |             34 | 2006-11-02  | 2007-11-02 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               36 |             38 | 2009-05-13  | 2011-02-09 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               38 |             39 | 2011-04-07  | 2012-06-16 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               40 |             41 | 2012-12-12  | 2014-11-16 |
| Prac1    | P2    |               41 |             45 | 2014-09-15  | 2017-12-21 |
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

This is what I want to transform it into. In a timeline for each patient:

```
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Practice | PatID | AgeAtActiveStart | AgeAtActiveEnd | ActiveStart | ActiveEnd  |  Status   |
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Prac1    | P1    |               58 |             72 | 2003-05-09  | 2018-01-04 | Active    |
| Prac1    | P2    |               32 |             33 | 2004-12-08  | 2006-07-18 | Active    |
| Prac1    | P2    |               33 |             33 | 2006-07-19  | 2006-11-01 | NotActive |
| Prac1    | P2    |               33 |             34 | 2006-11-02  | 2007-11-02 | Active    |
| Prac1    | P2    |               34 |             36 | 2007-11-03  | 2009-05-12 | NotActive |
| Prac1    | P2    |               36 |             38 | 2009-05-13  | 2011-02-09 | Active    |
| Prac1    | P2    |               38 |             38 | 2011-02-10  | 2011-04-06 | NotActive |
| Prac1    | P2    |               38 |             39 | 2011-04-07  | 2012-06-16 | Active    |
| Prac1    | P2    |               39 |             40 | 2012-06-17  | 2012-12-11 | NotActive |
| Prac1    | P2    |               40 |             45 | 2012-12-12  | 2017-12-21 | Active    |
+----------+-------+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Appreciate any help with this. Many thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do it?   What attempt have you made to solve this, and what error did you get?

Comment: I couldn't possibly think of a logic that I could run in t-SQL. Also, I’m running out of time,  That’s why I post this. Original dataset contains more than 1milion records.

Comment: **I’m running out of time**, So do we have time to write queries for you.

Comment: Sorry to have troubled you! I said 'I'm running out of time' in reply to the question from Tab Alleman, to indicate that I'm not posting the question out of laziness, but after having spent time on it and since I could not figure out an efficient way to do it. It needed lot of work to get the data set to the format in the top table, however I seem to have hit a brick wall and needing some advice.

Comment: Initially I did not expect the Active start-Active end periods to be overlapping. Since some of them are overallaping, now I need to combine all overlapping time periodes into one block and get the start and end dates for each such block. I used LAG and LEAD to get the start and end values shown on the top.

Comment: @Evan *It needed lot of work to get the data set to the format in the top table*  Please post your original data structure, as there is probably a much simpler solution available that doesn't need to rely on your half solution so far.  If anything, I would say having your data in the format provided is what is creating the problems in getting it to your desired format.